# Capybara selecting option from drop down

Tags: ruby

I have reviewed a number of solutions from stackoverflow to no avail. I was hoping someone could help me understand the error of my ways.

The haml markup looks like:

```
.graduation-date-range
            %label Graduation Date Range
            .row-fluid
              .span6
                .control-group
                  .controls
                    .bfh-selectbox{:id => "graduation_start_year", :style => "width: 100%"}
                      = f.hidden_field :graduation_start_date
                      %a.bfh-selectbox-toggle{"data-toggle" => "bfh-selectbox", :href => "#", :role => "button"}
                        %span.bfh-selectbox-option Start Year
                        %b.caret
                      .bfh-selectbox-options
                        %div{:role => "listbox"}
                          %ul.start-years{:role => "option"}
                            - (2012..2018).each do |y|
                              %li
                                %a{"data-option" => y, :href => "#"}= y
                  .help-inline

              .span6
                .control-group
                  .controls
                    .bfh-selectbox{:style => "width: 100%"}
                      = f.hidden_field :graduation_end_date
                      %a.bfh-selectbox-toggle{"data-toggle" => "bfh-selectbox", :href => "#", :role => "button"}
                        %span.bfh-selectbox-option End Year
                        %b.caret
                      .bfh-selectbox-options
                        %div{:role => "listbox"}
                          %ul.end-years{:role => "option"}
                            - (2012..2018).each do |y|
                              %li
                                %a{"data-option" => y, :href => "#"}= y
                  .help-inline
```

The solution I am currently trying to employ:

```
select('2012', :from => 'graduation_start_year', :visible => false)
```

I receive :

> Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find select box "graduation_start_year"

My understanding is that  either the label, name, or ID can be used to select from but I may be mistaken.

Thank you in advance to those who respond.

Comment: What is your capybara driver? You can check it adding `puts Capybara.current_driver` in the middle of your test.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not a form select box, but an html list that has been turned into something that resembles a dropdown box via javascript and CSS.

capybara select is looking for  `<select>` and `<option>` tags.   This is going to require a js type test with selenium or poltergeist to test.